# How can we use a trigger in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have reached the ibm site but I cant find the actual logic to make use of the trigger.

I have done the below code but how can i receive an intimation from the trigger?

```
public void setTrigger()
        {
        try{
            Queue = QMGR.accessQueue(queueName, (MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE+MQC.MQOO_SET));
            Queue.setTriggerControl(1);
            Queue.setTriggerType(2);
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println("trigger method");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("************************");
            }
        }
```

How can I get the intimation whenever message came.

Comment: Triggering is used to allow MQ to trigger a process to consume messages.  In some cases the triggering type requires that the application set the queue back to TRIGGER status which is what the code you posted looks like it is attempting to do.

Comment: Are you looking to have MQ actually start a Java process to consume messages from the queue?

Comment: Yes I want to start a java process to consume message from the queue, whenever I have the message in queue.

Comment: Any reason to not run a process in the background like a MDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, don't do the triggering setup via an application.  It is a waste of time.

Secondly, read & understand these MQ web pages:

- [Starting IBM MQ applications using triggers > Prerequisites for triggering](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026920_.htm)
- [Starting IBM MQ applications using triggers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026910_.htm)

Third, for Java applications, create a batch file or Unix script to set up any environment variables i.e. CLASSPATH and set batch file or Unix script in the PROCESS's APPLICID field.

Fourth, after you do the MQSC definition for the queue and process, don't forgot to start the trigger monitor (otherwise nothing will be triggered).

Fifth, if you set Trigger Type of First then make absolutely sure that the triggered application reads every message from the queue before exiting.

Sixth, triggering (Trigger First) is only good for scenarios when there are large gaps between messages or large gaps between burst of messages.  If you are receiving messages every second or 2 then triggering is not good because the application start, process & exit every second or 2.  And if it is a Java application, you will always have the JVM load time.

Seventh, if what you really wanted was Message CallBack (Asynchronous) rather than MQ Triggering then go read: [Asynchronous consumption of IBM MQ messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023050_.htm)

Comment: Is it still advisable to compare backout count and backout threshold to ensure the message being retrieved isn't poison?

Comment: Yes and poison messages should be put to an application backout queue not to the System's dead letter queue.